# 2017 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election

Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair's [second moderator election](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/election/2) has come to a close, the votes have been tallied, and the new moderator is:

[image: Nick C]

They'll be joining [the existing crew](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) shortly — please thank them for volunteering, and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes!

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/election/2), or [view a summary report online](https://www.opavote.com/results/5138071142006784/0).

Answer (score 10):

Congratulations Nick - well deserved!

Comment: That's a comment, not an answer :D

Comment: I was hoping that @NickC would say that, and with his new modly powers would sweep it over to a comment :-)

Comment: It's not an answer, but then the question isn't technically a question, it's more of an announcement.... Thanks Rory!

Comment: I don't want to add another not-answer, so congrats Nick! :)